# Java arrays.fill issue

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MainClass {
    int[] integer=new int[10];
    Arrays.fill(integer,1,4,5);
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this line `Arrays.fill(integer,1,4,5)` is wrong. As I understand `Arrays.fill` works like this (name of array,from point, to point, value)

Comment: Seems fine to me. What is your problem?

Comment: @Keppil see my answer. It's actually too obvious. ;-)

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Do you have an error message from the compiler, or an `Exception` when you run it?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Ah. :)

Comment: The red x on the left says this Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", delete this token
 - Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected

Comment: Voted to close as "Too localized".

Answer (score 5):

Because the line is not in a method.

When is it supposed to be executed?

If you want it to be executed at object construction time, palce it in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Add the statements within the body of a main method to execute them.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String [] args)
        int[] integer=new int[10];
        Arrays.fill(integer,1,4,5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your code inside method.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] integer = new int[10];
        Arrays.fill(integer, 1, 4, 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not wrong i guess...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] integer = new int[10];

        Arrays.fill(integer, 1, 4, 5);

        for(int i=0; i<integer.length; i++){
            System.out.println(integer[i]);
        }
}
```

This will print all values to 0, but for values for integer[1] to integer[4] will be printed 5.